# How can I Process Two Elements at a Time with an Odd Number of Elements

Tags: python, loops

I want to process X number of items at a time and do so dynamically. By that I mean that at run-time I need to determine if I want to process 1, 2, 3, or 4 items in a single loop. Below I hard-coded how I'm doing it for two items, but what if I want to do it for 4? Looking for a scalable and elegant approach.

Furthermore, if I need to process 2 at a time, and my list has 7 elements, I don't want to not process the last element.

Thank you!

Hardcoded:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> for i,k in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]):
...     print(f'{i},  {k}')
...
```

Result:

```
1,  2
3,  4
5,  6
```

**Notice above how 7 is missing**

Answer (score 0):

While using `data[1::2]`, you get only 3 values i.e. 2,4,6.
So you'll get only 3 answers like this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but you haven't answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to chose how many elements you want to process in each loop iteration:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

from itertools import islice

def process_elements(data, n=2):
    it = [islice(data, i, None, n) for i in range(n)]

    for vals in zip(*it):
        print('Processing elements:', *vals)

process_elements(data, 3)
```

Prints:

```
Processing elements: 1 2 3
Processing elements: 4 5 6
```

For `process_elements(data, 2)`:

```
Processing elements: 1 2
Processing elements: 3 4
Processing elements: 5 6
```

EDIT: Changed to `itertools.islice`